# Average percent

Tags: math, percentage

I'm dealing with some math problems here. We have the average sale and loss number in 3 stores.

```
Site     SALE     LOSS          % LOSS
-------------------------------------------
Store 1  474750   336740    70,92996314   (LOSS*100)/SALE
Store 2  321920   247810    76,97875249   
Store 3  149240   118440    79,36210131
-------------------------------------------
Total    945910   702990    74,31890983
```

If i sum the loss percentages of store 1,2 and 3 i get an average of 75.75.
But when i calculate the total SALE and LOSS and calculate the percentage LOSS i get 74.31?

Shouldent the numbers match? Or is this the wrong way?

Thank you for all answers!

Comment: Hint; each row percent loss is a fraction **with different denominators**. You can't just add them up. The proper way to average in the totals rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't average percentages when they're taken from different totals.  Calculating the total sale and loss is the correct way to do the calculation.

See [Averaging Percentages](https://web.archive.org/web/20171208124633/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57604.html) on the Ask Dr. Math forum.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same only if the Sales are equal on the 3 stores.

In general:

```
(A+B+C)/(D+E+F) != (A/D+B/E+C/F)/3
```

But imagine equal sales D=E=F

```
(A+B+C)/(D+E+F) = (A+B+C)/(3D) 
(A/D+B/E+C/F)/3 = (A/D+B/D+C/D)/3 = (A+B+C)/(3D)
```